# KFilter Library Setup for Smooth GPS Train Positions

Tags: c++, gps, smoothing, kalman-filter

I'm using [this Kalman Filter library](http://kalman.sourceforge.net/index.php) to smooth out the position data when jitter occurs. I'm not quite sure how to implement it according to my specifications, since the only example provided is for a plane and looks a little too complicated for what I'm looking for.

Basically I will be using this library for either a train or a worker, that provide GPS locations in latitude/longitude coordinates. Would someone be able to tell me what values to use for the needed varibales, the setDims() function, and the make..() (makeA(), makeH(), makeProcess(), makeMeasure(), etc...) functions?

It would be a huge help! Thanks!

Comment: for this you need to describe your model. what do the state vector, measurement vector, system matrix and so on look like in your case?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not really sure.. I keep getting confused as to what each means and how to determine what each should look like. I'm pretty confident that my state vector will be position and velocity coordinates in x and y -> x = [px, py, vx, vy] but I'm not sure how to go about the rest of it

Comment: If you really want to work with lat and long, you need to involve some math and geodesy to calculate measured x and y positions of the train on the "flat Earth". For some easier example you may assume your measurements are already those positions. In this case the Kalman stuff will be not that complicated. Would it work for you or do you really need the "real world" example with lat and long?

Comment: Yes that would work for me! I already have a function that takes the lat/long coordinates and converts them into x and y positions!

Comment: I also have a question, will the set up for the Kalman Filter be different for a train moving at train speeds (~50km/h) and for a worker just walking (~5km/h)?